# c# REST Controller accepts range of names for complex object property

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have an endpoint with a complex object as an argument. When it is called a user supplies a JSON object.

```
public class ComplexObject
{
    [JsonProperty("multiNamedProperty")]
    public string MultiNamedProperty { get; set; }
    public dynamic OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public double NumberProperty { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult MethodName(ComplexObject poco)
{
    this.ServiceName.PerformLogic(poco);
}
```

I want to be able to supply the endpoint a ComplexObject but have a set of names available for the property that all map like "name", "1", "banana", "n4m3", "fullName" etc.

Example expected object:

```
{
    thisStringCouldBeAnything: "notNullValue",
    bananaBananaTerracottaPie: { 
        banana: ["terracotta", "pie"],
        terracotta: "pie"
    },
    numberProperty: 0
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the ComplexObject might have an unpredictable set of property names? It's not quite clear specifically what you mean, from your description. Can you give a direct example of the JSON you want to send.

Comment: Have updated it with an example input

Comment: You can start with a `JDocument`

Comment: I see. It might be possible to deserialise it to a Dictionary instead, then

Comment: What about this `bananaBananaTerracottaPie`? Is this dynamic too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a mix of Dictionary and JDocument. But this would mean that you need to slightly restructure the expected object if you want to map it to class.

Example,

```json
{
    properties: {
      thisStringCouldBeAnything: "notNullValue",
      bananaBananaTerracottaPie: { 
        banana: ["terracotta", "pie"],
        terracotta: "pie"
        },
      numberProperty: 0
    }
   
}
```

C# class

```cs
public class ComplexObject
{
    Dictionary<string,JDocument> Properties {get;set;}
}
```

Alternatively, you could directly use the Dictionary in the parameter without using the class,

```
public ActionResult GetSomething(Dictionary<string,JDocument>  properties)
{

}
```